# How to get rid of NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe error in Spark Streaming + Kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to use Spark Streaming and connect it with Kafka. However I still get NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe error and now I just do not know what to do next.

My setup:

Ubuntu 16.04

Scala 2.11

Kafka 2.11-1.0.0 (I have also tried to use 2.11-0.10.0.0)

Spark 2.2.1

Hadoop 2.9.0

I cannot even run the example script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("example-pyspark-read-and-write").getOrCreate() 

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = sparkSession\
  .readStream\
  .format("kafka")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
  .option("kafka.partition.assignment.strategy", "range") \
  .option("subscribe", "test")\
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
  .load() 

query = df.writeStream\
    .format("console")\
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I run it on Spark using

```
spark-submit --master local[2] --jars /home/some_path/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar spark_streaming_kafka_example.py
```

And I get an error

```
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 38ee73d5-4f20-41d0-ac89-a29c3f3255d1, runId = dadfc8ab-8e4c-464f-b4ef-495426aafc88]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.createConsumer(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.<init>(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/some_path/spark_streaming_kafka_example.py", line 41, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 106, in awaitTermination
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 75, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 38ee73d5-4f20-41d0-ac89-a29c3f3255d1, runId = dadfc8ab-8e4c-464f-b4ef-495426aafc88]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {}\n\nCurrent State: INITIALIZING\nThread State: RUNNABLE'
```

I have also tried to include spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.2.1 in --jars (instead of spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar), but it didn't help either.

Also I have tried to put those two lines in spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /home/some_path/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.2.1.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /home/some_path/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.2.1.jar
```

OR

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /home/some_path/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /home/some_path/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

Try running `export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10` before your `spark2-submit` command.
[*[Source for solution]*](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/KafkaConsumer-subscribe-0-9-vs-0-10-in-Structured-streaming/m-p/62182/highlight/true#M2753)

Comment: this answer should get more like

Answer (score 2):

In order to use Spark Structured Streaming along with Kafka, you need to add following JAR too in `spark.driver.extraClassPath` & `spark.executor.extraClassPath`:

> /home/some_path/kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar

Since `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar` does not contain `KafkaConsumer`, we need to add above-mentioned JAR file too. So, the final `spark-submit` command will be like this:

> spark-submit --master local[2] --jars /home/some_path/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.2.1.jar:/home/some_path/kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar spark_streaming_kafka_example.py

Also, since you are using Spark Structured Streaming and not Spark Streaming, so, you don't need to include any `spark-streaming` JAR.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I double checked I have all the versions of kafka and sql-streaming etc. unified and added `kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar` to both spark-submit and `spark.driver.extraClassPath` & `spark.executor.extraClassPath`, but it didn't help much.
I  still cannot construct a kafka consumer:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/some_path/read_kafka_stream_structured.py", line 45, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
...
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'Failed to construct kafka consumer\n=== Streaming Query ===\
...`

Comment: Also, I have added kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar
(The kafka-clients jar is the same version: kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar, I can no longer edit my above comment)

Comment: You shouldn't need `kafka-clients` as core Kafka is already a transitive dependency `spark-sql-kafka` http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.1.1

Comment: @cricket_007 That's correct. But we still face `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe` even though we provide `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar`. I don't know why. Do you know the reason for it?

Comment: Not sure, but I bet you this commit fixed it. https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/03367d7aa3acd3abbcacba57ea75c8efa2a9a794

Comment: Yeah...it looks like it is fixed. But in v2.3.0, not in earlier versions. Also, we need to be sure about it.

Comment: am still facing the same issue...
am using:

 - kafka 2.4.0 
 - spark 2.4.5