# Spark 2.1.0 connection with Kafka 0.9.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Kafka 0.9.0 and Spark 2.1.0
My Spark Submit is as follows:

```
./spark-submit --jars /home/cnbo/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.cloudera1.jar --class ClickStream /home/cnbo/jars/sparkstreamingfi_2.11-0.1.jar
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
```

I know there is version conflict for 0.9 to 0.10. But I want to run My application on Kafka 0.9.0. 
What needs to be done now?
what external jar I should use instead of:

```
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.cloudera1.jar
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

In order to use Spark along with Kafka, you need to add following JAR too in `spark.driver.extraClassPath` & `spark.executor.extraClassPath`:

> /home/cnbo/jars/kafka-clients-0.9.0.0.jar

Since `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.cloudera1.jar` does not contain `KafkaConsumer`, we need to add above-mentioned JAR file too. So, the final `spark-submit` command will be like this:

> ./spark-submit --jars /home/cnbo/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.cloudera1.jar:/home/cnbo/jars/kafka-clients-0.9.0.0.jar --class ClickStream /home/cnbo/jars/sparkstreamingfi_2.11-0.1.jar

I hope it helps!

Comment: You shouldn't be able to use `kafka-0-10_2.11` with brokers running 0.9, should you?

Comment: @cricket_007 I haven't tested the use of `kafka-0-10_2.11` with brokers running 0.9. But I assume that different Kafka versions have backward compatibility. Also, using kafka 0.10 would be better, but, the question was specifically asked for 0.9.

Comment: It's not compatible... That's why there was a version increase. Also, Spark maintains two different Kafka libraries. Structured streaming only possible with Kafka 0.10+ https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Well then, it's up to the person, who asked the question, should comment on it, i.e., whether the application was able to run with Kafka 0.9 or not. If not, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: I doubt adding older, incompatible JAR files into the classpath will make it work, which is why I'm confused this is accepted. Sure, the class exists, but other problems will result from this

Comment: @cricket_007 I am confused too. There is a similar question like this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708620/how-to-get-rid-of-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-kafka-clients-consumer-kafkacons/48711881#48711881. There the user is using Kafka 0.10. But of course for structured streaming. Here I am not sure whether it is for spark streaming or structured streaming.

Comment: Hi People, Sorry for the late reply. I have taken back the acceptance of this answer as I am using Structured Streaming with Kafka 0.9.0 version. My Spark is not able to consume any data from kafka topic and also it is not throwing any error. Only the Folders are getting created with spark_metadata file. But I have solved the kafkaConsumer.subscribe error and awarded an Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Spark Kafka page, you'd have seen

> 0.8 integration is compatible with later **0.9** and 0.10 brokers, but **the 0.10 integration is not compatible with earlier brokers**

Therefore, you need this library

```
spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11
```

And if you want structured streaming, you need to actually upgrade Kafka to support the new consumer API

Comment: so there is no way I can use structured streaming with Kafka 0.9.0 ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Kafka 0.10 added support for timestamps in the record, which I believe make the dataframe support over time-framed data possible.